# AWS lambda console error failed to write json

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Was trying to follow the tutorial [How to build an API with Lambdas and API Gateway](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-api-with-lambdas-and-api-gateway-11254e23b703/) and ran into some errors:

Been trying for a long time. Any explanation for the errors when added json into the code editor?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.httpMethod === 'PUT') {
        let response = putShows(event)
        return done(response);
    } else if (event.httpMethod === 'GET') {
        let response = getShows(event);
        return done(response);
    }
};

const done = response => {
    return {
        statusCode: '200',
        body: JSON.stringify(response),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    }
}

const Showss = {
    action: 'Game of Thrones',
    fantasy: 'Supernatural',
    animated: 'The Simpsons',
    western: 'Westworld',
    superhero: 'The Flash',
    musical: '30 Rock',
    crime: 'Sherlock',
    comedy: 'Friends',
    adventure: 'Doctor Who',
    war: 'Wounded Love',
    guy: 'The Walking Dead',
    romance: "Grey's Anatomy",
    thriller: 'Sharp Objects',
    horror: 'American Horror Story'
}

const getShows = event => {
    let genre = event.pathParameters.genre;
    return Showss[genre];
}

const putShows = event => {
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: image of error]

Comment: Can you add the code directly here

Comment: added thanks so much

Comment: which browser you are using? did you try on some other browser?

Comment: working fine for me, As @Adiii said, the problem must be your browser.  try on another browser and let us know

Comment: thanks so much. it is a browser issue. thanks a lot appreciate it.

Comment: @excitelybored If your question is unlikely to help future readers, please feel free to Delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different browser or clear the cache in your browser.